# R XLConnect getting index/formula to a chunk of data using content found in first cell

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

Sorry if this is difficult to understand - I don't have enough karma to add a picture so I will do the best I can to describe this! Using XLConnect package within R to read & write from/to Excel spreadsheets.

I am working on a project in which I am trying to take columns of data out of many workbooks and concatenate them together into rows of a new workbook based on which workbook they came from (each workbook is data from a consecutive business day). The snag is that the data that I seek is only a small part (10 rows X 3 columns) of each workbook/worksheet and is not always located in the same place within the worksheet due to sloppiness on behalf of the person who originally created the spreadsheets. (e.g. I can't just start at cell A2 because the dataset that starts at A2 in one workbook might start at B12 or C3 in another workbook).

I am wondering if it is possible to search for a cell based on its contents (e.g. a cell containing the title "Table of Arb Prices") and return either the index or reference formula to be able to access that cell.

Also wondering if, once I reference that cell based on its contents, if there is a way to adjust that formula to get to where I know another cell is compared to that one. For example if a cell with known contents is always located 2 rows above and 3 columns to the left of the cell where I wish to start collecting data, is it possible for me to take that first reference formula and increment it by 2 rows and 3 columns to get the reference formula for the cell I want?

Thanks for any help and please advise me if you need further information to be able to understand my questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read the entire worksheet in as a matrix with something like

```
library(XLConnect)
demoExcelFile <- system.file("demoFiles/mtcars.xlsx", package = "XLConnect")
mm <- as.matrix(readWorksheetFromFile(demoExcelFile, sheet=1))
class(mm)<-"character" # convert all to character
```

Then you can search for values and get the row/colum

```
 which(mm=="3.435", arr.ind=T)

#      row col
# [1,]  23   6
```

Then you can offset those and extract values from the matrix how ever you like. In the end, when you know where you want to read from, you can convert to a cleaner data frame with

```
read.table(text=apply(mm[25:27, 6:8],1,paste, collapse="\t"), sep="\t")
```

Hopefully that gives you a general idea of something you can try. It's hard to be more specific without knowing exactly what your input data looks like.